# Pole bending simulation

Tags: physics

I'm quite new to Blender and I'm currently struggling to find a good way to simulate pole bending with physics. The goal is to bend a mesh cylinder like a fishing rod or a fiber-glass tent pole would do when bringing the two extremities close to each other.
I have been trying with soft body physics but without success yet. I would like to stick to soft body physics so the rod can still react to a wind forcefield for example.
Is it something possible to be done in Blender ?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need here is high forces-- higher than are generally used for soft body, and higher than soft body is probably designed to simulate.

[image]

Here, I started with a simple string, with the base 2 verts assigned to a goal group, and maxed out edge strengths (incl. bending 10.0, not shown), but that wasn't enough.

Then I created some additional crossbars for each vert.  What bending does is create virtual edges that join every vertex to each of its neighbor-of-neighbor vertices.  These virtual edges then resist expansion/contraction, leading to less bending allowed along the main string.  After doing this, tuning to a bending value of 1.0 was appropriate for the spring I was looking for.

For purposes of rendering, I masked away these crossbar verts before my skin modifier.  Edge collision is most appropriate for this kind of softbody.  Vertex density will have a lot to do with how flexible softbody physics are (fewer vertices = fewer degrees of freedom.)  To maintain a similar flexibility at a different size, you need to maintain vertex density rather than just scale the structure up and apply.  For example, this stick is about 4 units long; if I wanted a stick next to it, that seemed like it was made out of the same material, that was 8 units long, I would want about twice as many verts in that longer stick.  If you want something to be more flexible as it reaches one end, like a fishing pole, you should have higher vertex density on that side.

If you need to transfer soft body physics onto a more detailed mesh than that shown, you'll probably want to use a surface deform or mesh deform modifier rather than run physics directly on the detailed mesh.  Using a skin modified mesh to do that is dangerous (topology can change with significant expansion/contraction of edges), but here, it should be okay.